# Python API for Amazon EC2 that supports files

Tags: python, api, amazon-ec2

The command line tool [ec2-run-instances](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonEC2/dg/2006-10-01/CLTRG-run-instances.html) takes a -f parameter to pass a file to the instance at run time. Are there any Python APIs for EC2 that do the equivalent?

I'm looking to customize a Wowza Media Server, which requires passing in a file when booting up a new image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use boto. Then you can possibly code a small script to open a file first and read it's contents and pass it as user-data.

Or try http://github.com/fschulze/mr.awsome

Comment: Mr. Awesome is indeed awesome. In this case I need something a bit more scriptable (accessible via Python code directly and not via the command line. In this case I'm going with boto and then uploading scripts and executing them via Paramiko http://www.lag.net/paramiko/